# My Passport Essential external usb 3.0 drive runs at usb 2.0 speed

Tags: usb-drive

0 WD My passport drive plugged into a (blue) usb 3.0 port. I mount it and it transfers at about 14MByte/sec. Under windows 7 (I have dual boot) it transfers at about 120 to 230 MByte/sec on the same port.
lsusb listing is:

```
Bus 008 Device 004: ID 1058:0730 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 03f0:0024 Hewlett-Packard KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0458:0007 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:08b2 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 4000
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am using the correct port and there is no fault with the drive. All works correctly under windows 7.
I am using Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit natty with all the updates.
dmesg gives:

```
2510.028644] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2510.028656] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[ 2510.152518] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint
[ 2578.450633] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[     2578.450992] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[ 2578.451364] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[ 2578.451744] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[ 2578.452119] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[ 2578.452490] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep
[ 2578.453739] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a lot like the kernel isn't driving this device properly.

It's not a great solution, but it might be interesting to boot Ubuntu Oneiric alpha from a USB stick and see how that performs, or try the Oneiric kernel.  If nobody answers here, I suggest you [file a kernel bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, edit grub file:

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
pci=nomsi
```

after adding the `pci=nomsi` save and exit (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then press Y then press ENTER).

Then execute:

```
sudo nano update-grub
```

Reboot and USB 3.0 should be working, when mounting PENs, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming the drive has an NTFS file system on it, which is known to run slower under Linux than Windows. I myself have a WD external drive and the same thing happens.

There is no method I know of that can fix this, apart from putting a different file system on the drive, which, if your using Windows 7 as well, would not be something I suggest doing.

Comment: what would NTFS have to do with `xhci_hcd` errors?